# I can't compile telegram source code with NDK

Tags: android-studio, compilation, cygwin, telegram, ndk-build

I installed NDK and set the NDK path in "Project Structure" :

[image: Like this]

And then I added below codes to `build.gradle`:

```
task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') 
{
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
                '-C', file('jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all',
                'NDK_DEBUG=1'
}

task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
    def ndkDir = android.ndkDirectory
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd",
                '-C', file('jni').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
                'clean'
}

clean.dependsOn 'cleanNative'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn buildNative
}
```

And add this code to "`defauilConfig`" in `build.gradle` :

```
ndk {
       moduleName "TMessagesProj"
}
```

---

When I try to build an APK , I get this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:buildNative'.
>   Process 'command 'C:\Users\Mehran\AppData\Local\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r12/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

This is the Messages Console :

> make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
>   make: *** [D:/Mehran/AndroidStudioProjects/TelegramTest/TMessagesProj/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/tmessages.22/./opus/src/opus_encoder.o] Error 2
>   make: Leaving directory `D:/Mehran/AndroidStudioProjects/TelegramTest/TMessagesProj/jni'

---

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I miss to see why cygwin tag is relevant to the question

Comment: Because Cygwin help to compile c/c++ classes in java project And I problem with c/c++ classes :))